# MongoDB: Update multiple documents but do NOT upsert

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update a specific field in  few documents but do NOT want to insert that field if it is NOT present in any document. For example if I have following three documents in a collection "test":

```
{
Name: "abc",
Age: 10,
Hits: 1,
Score: 100
},
{
Name: "def",
Age: 20,
Hits: 1,
Score: 50
},
{
Name: "ghi",
Age: 30,
Score: 100
}
```

I have tried this command :

```
 db.test.update({},{$set:{Hits:2}},{multi:true,upsert:false})
```

here is the output:

```
    {
    Name: "abc",
    Age: 10,
    Hits: 2,
    Score: 100
    },
    {
    Name: "def",
    Age: 20,
    Hits: 2,
    Score: 50
    },
    {
    Name: "ghi",
    Age: 30,
    Score: 100,
    Hits: 2
   }
```

My expected output is :

```
    {
    Name: "abc",
    Age: 10,
    Hits: 2,
    Score: 100
    },
    {
    Name: "def",
    Age: 20,
    Hits: 2,
    Score: 50
    },
    {
    Name: "ghi",
    Age: 30,
    Score: 100
    }
```

Basically, I am not expecting the Third document with name "ghi" to have the field "Hits".
Please let me know your thoughts.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a filter for update:

```
db.test.update({Hits: {$exists: true}}, {$set: {Hits: 2}}, {multi:true, upsert:false})
```

Comment: Thanks Stalk. It helps to solve the issue. But, I fail to understand why "upsert:false" is not helping here. Ideally, upsert:false should come handy. Now, even if we remove "upsert:false", the output doesnt change. Isn't it?

Comment: [upsert:false](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) just tells that mongodb shall not create new document, if no document matches our filter. But here we are using [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/), which not create a document, but update it. I think, that in case of `$set` option `upsert` is not necessary.

Comment: well.. I am trying to replicate the example from Mongodb.org website. Here they have used MULTI & UPSERT while using Update with $set. I copied the following lines from that website:    The following operation specifies both the multi option and the upsert option. If matching documents exist, the operation updates all matching documents. If no matching documents exist, the operation inserts a new document.

db.books.update(
   { item: "EFG222" },
   { $set: { reorder: false, tags: [ "literature", "translated" ] } },
   { upsert: true, multi: true }
)

Comment: Here is the link : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-method-examples

Comment: @VamsiKiran yes, i see. So, if you don't want to create new document when no documents were matched, then add `upsert:false`, regardless of using `$set`. In example from answer above, if we'll omit `upsert:false`, then one document `{Hits: 2}` will be created if no documents will be found by query `{Hits: {$exists: true}}`.